# fullcalendar does not set 'id' in events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using `fullcalendar` and am seeing events in the various views.  What I am not seeing are the event ids.  I set them like:

```
    'eventSources': [
        {
            'events': function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.get({
                    'url': "/GetUEvents",
                    'contentType': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'traditional': true,
                    'data': {
                        'start': start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                        'end': end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                    }
                }).done(function(ajaxData, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                    var events = [];
                    var now = moment().local();

                    $(ajaxData.eventList).each(function() {
                        var myEnd = moment($(this).attr("end")).local();
                        var myStart = moment($(this).attr("start")).local();
                        var myId = "a" + $(this).attr("id");

                        if (myEnd <= now) {
                            events.push({
                                'title': "",
                                'start': myStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                                'end': myEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                                'id': myId,
                                'className': "entriesOld"
                            });
                        } else {
                            events.push({
                                'title': "",
                                'start': myStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                                'end': myEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                                'id': myId,
                                'className': "entriesFuture"
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    callback(events);
                });
            }
        }
    ]
```

If I set the "title" to the id value then it is displayed: `'title': myId,`.

I don't know if it should be a `span` item or DOM object id or class name or an html5 `data` element.  It is not showing up in any of thise places.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The official doc says that the [Event Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) has two **required** variable, the `title` and the `start`.

I think, becuase in your code the `title` is an empty `String`, the fullcalendar does not process your event(s).

Comment: Good info but not the case here.  Setting the empty title to a value does nothing to the id.

Comment: Ohh my bad, sorry but its a good warning.. or is it working with empty `String` as well?
On the other hand what is the output of `console.log($(this).attr("id"));`?

Comment: Oh, the "id" element has a value.  I have used it as the "title" vale to make sure.  I may have found the answer though in the `eventRender` method.  I might be able to put the id value in the display with that.